# RecursionError when trying to implement both __getattribute__/__setattr__ and _getitem__/__setitem__ in python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, class, recursion

I'm running into the dreaded `RecursionError` while trying to implement a class that essentially acts as a proxy between a private variable `_threads`. The idea is for the class to act as a thread-aware dictionary, dishing out the correct dictionary assigned to a specific thread for each call to the class instance.

##### **Background** (Feel free to skip it if you don't care)

I found myself needing this while parallelizing some reporting code that spans across many functions originally accessing many (consistent) instance variables. The class is basically a way to avoid having to grab the current thread identity within each function and manually doing the lookup in an instance dictionary. Plus, for re-usability in other projects I figured why not!

### Current Code

```py
import threading

class ThreadManager(object):
    """
    A custom thread-aware class for managing multiple sets of variables
    without the need to keep track of the current, working thread
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        assert threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread(), \
            "ThreadManager must be instantiated from MainThread"
        self._threads = dict()
        self._thread_vars = dict(**dict.fromkeys(args), **kwargs)

    @property
    def thread(self) -> dict:
        ident = self.thread_id
        if ident not in self._threads:
            # new thread, create new key/value pair with default thread_vars dict as value
            self._threads[ident] = self._thread_vars
        return self._threads[ident]

    @property
    def thread_id(self) -> int:
        return threading.current_thread().ident

    def update(self, data: dict) -> None:
        ident = self.thread_id
        for var, value in data.items():
            if var not in self._thread_vars:
                raise AttributeError("%r was not found in the list of original thread variables" % var)
            self._threads[ident][var] = value

    def clear(self) -> None:
        """Clears a single thread's variables and re-instates the default values"""
        ident = self.thread_id
        self._threads[ident].clear()
        self._threads[ident].update(self._thread_vars)

    # region dunders
    def __setattr__(self, var, value):
        """
        >>> tm = ThreadManager("a", "b", c=False)
        >>> tm.b
        >>> tm.b = "data"
        >>> tm.b
        "data"
        """
        print(f"__setattr__: var={var}, value={value}")
        _ = self.thread  # FIXME: Hacky way to ensure the thread and accompanying dict exist before updating it
        self._threads[self.thread_id][var] = value

    def __getattr__(self, var):
        """
        >>> tm = ThreadManager("a", "b", c=False)
        >>> tm.b
        >>> tm.c
        False
        """
        print(f"__getattr__: var={var}")
        return self.thread[var]

    def __setitem__(self, var, value):
        """
        >>> tm = ThreadManager("a", "b", c=False)
        >>> tm["b"]
        >>> tm["b"] = "data"
        >>> tm["b"]
        "data"
        """
        print(f"__setitem__: var={var}, value={value}")
        _ = self.thread  # FIXME: Hacky way to ensure the thread and accompanying dict exist before updating it
        self._threads[self.thread_id][var] = value

    def __getitem__(self, var):
        """
        >>> tm = ThreadManager("a", "b", c=False)
        >>> tm["b"]
        >>> tm["c"]
        False
        """
        print(f"__getitem__: var={var}")
        return self.thread[var]

    def __len__(self):
        """Total number of threads being managed"""
        return len(self._threads)
    # endregion

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tm = ThreadManager("a", "b", c={"d": 1})
```

Using the above code I end up with the `RecursionError` and traceback:

```
__setattr__: var=_threads, value={}
__getattr__: var=_threads
__getattr__: var=_threads
__getattr__: var=_threads
...
__getattr__: var=_threads
__getattr__: var=_threads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 1266, in <module>
    tm = ThreadManager("a", "b", c={"d": 1})
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 87, in __init__
    self._threads = dict()
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 125, in __setattr__
    _ = self.thread  # FIXME: Hacky way to ensure the thread and accompanying dict exist before updating it
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 93, in thread
    if ident not in self._threads:
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 136, in __getattr__
    return self.thread[var]
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 93, in thread
    if ident not in self._threads:
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 136, in __getattr__
    return self.thread[var]
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 93, in thread
    if ident not in self._threads:
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 136, in __getattr__
    return self.thread[var]
...
  File "C:/Users/mhill/PycharmProjects/reporting/app/reports/base.py", line 100, in thread_id
    return threading.current_thread().ident
  File "C:\Users\mhill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 1233, in current_thread
    return _active[get_ident()]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I'm trying to keep the abilities to both access the dictionary items as properties (using `tm.property_name`) and as you would a typical dictionary item (using `tm["property_name"]`), which is why I'm trying to implement both `__getattribute__/__setattr__` and `__getitem__/__setitem__`

Can anyone offer any insight on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you think `self.thread` means when you've implemented `__getattribute__`?

Comment: `self.thread` in `__getattribute__` calls the `thread` property, which returns the dictionary related to the current thread. I can tell it sounds like a recursive nightmare just by saying it, but I'm not sure how else to go about it.

Comment: "`self.thread` in `__getattribute__` calls the `thread` property" - nope. It calls `__getattribute__`.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__

Comment: I've tried utilizing `object.__getattribute__(self, var)`, but wasn't successful with implementing it properly since I need to access the underlying `self._threads` dictionary.

Comment: Can someone please try to explain how I can overcome this issue? I understand I'm not fully understanding the documentation, so some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your changes to your code make the accepted answer no longer make much sense, since you've removed the issue you used to be having and have replaced it with some new error. That breaks the way this site works, where questions and answers are supposed to be lasting things that can help future readers. If the answer below really did help you with one issue, but you still have more problems, ask new questions about the new issues (with perhaps links back here for context). Don't change the question in fundamental ways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly want to use `__getattr__` instead of `__getattribute__`.  The former is called only when the normal instance variable lookup fails, but the latter is ALWAYS called.  This is clearly explained in the documentation.  It also seems to be exactly what you want here, unless I'm missing something.  You want to be able to access certain variables in the normal way, for example `thread` and `update`, but you want to provide special functionality in other cases.  That's exactly what `__getattr__` is for.

It is very difficult to implement `__getattribute__` correctly, since you must handle all the variables that you want to access normally by explicitly calling `__getattr__` in those cases.  I don't see any reason why you have to do this.

My suggestion is to just replace `__getattribute__` by `__getattr__` and try to run your program again.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've changed everything to use `__getattr__` instead of `__getattribute__`, but am still running into the `RecursionError`. I've updated both the code snippet and traceback of my question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Your new problem is the `__setattr__` function and the first line of the constructor.  `__setattr__` tries to access the variable `_threads`, which calls `__getattr__` since the name `_threads` hasn't been set yet.  So you get recursion again.

Comment: But, how do I get around that? How am I supposed to declare instance variables in `__init__` and still be able to use `__setattr__` in the way I need to?

Comment: You have to be very careful with the function `__setattr__` since there are certain variables that you want to assign in the normal way (`_threads` and `_thread_vars`, for example).  You have to handle those as special cases by calling `super().__setattr__()`.

Comment: In your constructor you could place names directly into `__dict__`, for example self.__dict__['_thread'] = {}, which bypasses the `__setattr__` mechanism entirely.  That is pretty ugly but I don't see any "nice" way of doing it.

Comment: I tried doing an if/else in `__setattr__` to account for `_threads` and `_thread_vars` and using the call the parent class for them, but still ended up with the same issue. However, using the `self.__dict__` method in `__init__` did the trick. Thank you so much!